# Disable Materialize Framework "Responsiveness"

Tags: java, spring, materialize

I am attempting to use the [materialize](http://materializecss.com/cards.html) framework. I am very much liking the features it provides but I don't really care too much about making everything "responsive" right now. I would like to make things somewhat "static", meaning when I resize the browser, everything stays the same size (and user can scroll around in a smaller window to find what they want). I plan to later work on the full "responsiveness" to support things like mobile, window resizing, etc. Below shows whats currently happening. I downloaded the whole framework so I'm free to alter the .css that comes along with it, but I'm not really a .css expert so not really sure where to begin.

**Full Screen**

[image]

**Resized Screen - obviously cannot stay like this forever**

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your question directly: I assume you are using the Materialize grid? Meaning you have divs with class names like "col l6"? To have non responsive elements you should not use any materialize column class names. It will then just be regular old HTML and CSS that you define. Materialize only applies its CSS to elements that use its classnames.

Now for a recommendation: This will probably break some of the features of Materialize. Or at the very least, it will look gross and you will have to add padding/margins everywhere manually. Then if you want to go back and enable mobile responsiveness, you will have to manually remove all of that. You will also have to use old fashioned CSS rules to determine you element sizing. Every element will need a height and width rule applied to it. It is a lot harder to add mobile responsive classes later. It will save you a lot of time if you just do it now. It's quite easy in Materialize once you get the hang of it.

One of the main reasons that Materialize and Bootstrap and the like are used, is to make mobile responsive websites easy. It really is an essential skill to learn for web development these days.

Comment: wow I just picked this project back up today after a few weeks off, what a coincidence you posted today! I completely agree with what your stating. After I had posted this, I spent a little time playing with Materialize and got it working properly. there's too much code to post and it wouldn't be all that useful for anyone but its actually quite easy to use once you get the hang of it. I attached a new screenshot of what the forms look like now.